# newbie having trouble understanding selectors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I set up my user interface in an xib file and got everything working pretty well.  But the xib file was pretty cluttered, so I decided to try to create some of the buttons/bars/etc. programmatically instead.  I can get them to show up fine, but I'm doing something wrong with the selectors.

With an `instructions` button on the xib file, for instance, I just used the mouse to connect the `instructions` button with the `giveInstructions` method in the .h file, and everything was fine.  But when I try it programmatically, like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *instr = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instructions" 
                                                          style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:@selector(giveInstructions:)];
```

I get an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set the target. It will most likely be `self` as in when the button is pressed call the method `giveInstructions:` on this object

Comment: The error message explains that the instance (target, in your situation 'nil' or non-existent) doesn't recognise the selector `giveInstructions:`.

Comment: why everybody suggests that the crash is due to setting the target to nil? Messaging nil should be fine in Obj-C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you fixed the target problem, it is most likely that "giveInstructions" doesn't exist, at least not in this class's implementation.

If you have declared

```
- (void)giveInstructions:(id)sender;
```

In your .h, it is imperative that you have a matching implementation in your .m file, e.g.:

```
- (void)giveInstructions:(id)sender{
    //my code here
}
```

If you have done this already, then the only other thing I can think of that could be wrong is that in your `@selector(giveInstructions:)` the colon may be unnecessary if you don't have a sender, or any other arguments passed from the method.

**Note:** When calling `@selector` if the method you are calling is 1 character different from its actual declared name you will get this error because the selector doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, that's what did it!  `giveInstructions` didn't have any arguments.  So when I changed the selector to `@selector(giveInstructions)`, without the `:`, it worked fine.  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `target` should not be `nil` but rather the instance which should receive the action. That's probably `self` in your case, so try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *instr = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instructions" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(giveInstructions:)];
```

Comment: What does your method definition look like? Should be - (void)giveInstructions:(id)sender;

Comment: Yup, that was it--the method definition didn't take any arguments.  So when I took the colon out of the selector, everything worked fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The naming of the selector is important.

If it has one colon then it refers to a method that takes one argument

```
@selector(myMethod:)

- (void)myMethod:(id)sender;
```

if it does not have a colon then the method does not expect an argument

```
@selector(myMethod)

- (void)myMethod;
```

**Note** Although they both look like they have the same name they are in fact two different methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *instr = 
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instructions" 
style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(giveInstructions:)];
<-- change "nil" to "self" !
```

I think the target:`nil` should be `self` because those functions are belongs to this class file.